# WP_MAIL not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem with wp_mail function in wordpress. page is refunding me 404 error page. The action is written normally.
Here is my code

```
$aemail = $_POST['aemail'];
    $aname = $_POST['afname'].' '.$_POST['alname'];
    $aphone = $_POST['aphone'];
    $loanamount = $_POST['loan_amount'];
    $vehicle = $_POST['vehicle_make'];
    $year = $_POST['year'];
    $model = $_POST['model'];
    $miless = $_POST['miless'];
    $message = "Name : $aname"."\r\n";
    $message .= "Email : $aemail"."\r\n";
    $message .= "Phone : $aphone"."\r\n";
    $message .= "Loan Amount : $loanamount"."\r\n";
    $message .= "vehicle make : $vehicle"."\r\n";
    $message .= "Year : $year"."\r\n";
    $message .= "Model : $model"."\r\n";
    $message .= "Miless : $miless"."\r\n";
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0rn"; 
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1rn"; 
    $headers .= "From: $aemail\r\n"; 
    $headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$aemail."\r\n" .
    $headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    @wp_mail('.........@gmail.com', '"".', $message, $headers);
}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: page is refunding me 404 error page.

Comment: Please check is there any post_type you are using in your form name because once i got same error and i have used post_type name in form textbox name

Comment: <form name="" method="post"

Comment: @YatinKhullar what should be form name? Is it the same name of my button tag?

Comment: form does not have an name , and also , post the whole code of your file. seems like minor error

Comment: not saying about form name saying about textbox, textarea , radio button etc. name attributes and form also has name attribute @Arsh

Comment: `<form name="" method="post" action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/loan-request/" id="frmLoanRequest"><input type="text" name="afname" placeholder="First Name" id="afname" class="validate[required] text-input"/><input type="text" name="alname" placeholder="Last Name" id="alname" class="validate[required] text-input"/><input type="email" name="aemail" placeholder="Email Address" id="aemail" class="validate[required,custom[email]] text-input"/><input type="tel" name="aphone" placeholder="Phone Number" id="aphone" class="validate[required,custom[phone]] text-input"/>`

Comment: `<input type="text" name="loan_amount" placeholder="Loan Amount" id="loan_amount"  class="validate[required] text-input"/><input type="text" name="vehicle_make" placeholder="Vehicle Make" id="vehicle_make"  class="validate[required] text-input"/> <input type="text" name="year" placeholder="Year" id="year" class="validate[required] text-input"/><input type="text" name="model" placeholder="Model" id="model" class="validate[required] text-input"/>
<input type="text" name="miless" placeholder="Miless" id="miless" class="validate[required] text-input"/>`

Comment: `<button type="submit" name="submitapp" class="btn btn-lg">Get Started</button>`

Comment: must I write javascript to get workable form or only with php I can get it?